# Convert Slack messages into task list items

Tags: canvas, slack, tasklist

I want to take advantage of the new Canvas feature in Slack.
Has anyone figured out a way to take a conversation and convert it into a task list item in another channel?

Thank you in advance.

I have poked around the workflow builder and havent found anything that specifically addresses this.